# Why the compiler cannot include an external DCU in my package?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have this error:

> E2411 Unit %s in package %s refers to unit %s which is not found in
>   any package. Packaged units must refer only to packaged units (Delphi)

Delphi Help is extremely helpful and it says:

> No further information is available for this error or warning.

Why I can't refer to a unit that is not part of a package?

UPDATE:

Never-ending story: Putting the file in its own package breaks something else: [Unit GIFImg was compiled with a different version of CCR.Exif.Consts.SOutOfResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955973/unit-gifimg-was-compiled-with-a-different-version-of-ccr-exif-consts-soutofresou)
This is why I wanted NOT to put the file in its own package.

Comment: Hi David. I have seen the message. But I want to understand why is that. Why the compiler cannot include an external DCU in my package?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, it could do with some clarification. As it stands it is dangerously close to a circular definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't refer to a unit that is not part of a package because a package needs to be a self-contained piece of software. That means that a package must contain all units it uses or have them available through packages in its requires clause.

To solve this error you can either

- include the unit in the package that you are building, or
- add the package which contains that unit to the requires list of the package you are building.

Comment: So, as I thought it is not a matter of "I cannot compile that file" but rather "I don't (shouldn't) compile that file".

Comment: @Altar: hmm, yes, I guess you could put it like that as the compiler won't deal with units that are implicitely included (used but not explicitely included in any required package or the package being built)

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be

> Why does the compiler emit this error?

If you refer to unit A then that reference to unit A needs to be resolved. If it cannot be found in the current package, or another package in the requires clause, then the compiler simply cannot proceed.

You also ask:

> Why the compiler cannot include an external DCU in my package?

You can simply add the unit to your package in the contains clause of your .dpk file.

Comment: Putting the unit I need in its own package breaks down my Delphi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955973/unit-gifimg-was-compiled-with-a-different-version-of-ccr-exif-consts-soutofresou