# Unit GIFImg was compiled with a different version of CCR.Exif.Consts.SOutOfResources

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I was trying to use the [EXIF](http://code.google.com/p/ccr-exif/downloads/list) library in one of my packages. It worked before but now I get strange messages:

> [DCC Fatal Error] F2051 Unit GIFImg was compiled with a different
>   version of CCR.Exif.Consts.SOutOfResources

I don't really get it... Why Delphi tries to recompile one of its files? How do I fix this?

GifImg is located here:

> c:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\source\vcl\GIFImg.pas

Update:

I looked at the date of that file (1 PAS and 2 DCUs) and it has the same date as any other file in RAD Studio\8.0\source\vcl folder. So, the file was not accidentally modified.

**Update2:**

This is my uses clause:

```
USES Windows, SysUtils, AnsiStrings, Graphics, Dialogs, Classes, jPeg,
     pngImage,                     
     janFX,   //CCR.Exif,
     {$IFDEF VER150}
        GIFImageFinn     {Delphi 7}
     {$ELSE}  
        GIFImg           {Delphi 2010/XE}
     {$ENDIF}
     ;
```

If I comment the CCR.EXIF unit, it starts to compile my package. So, adding EXIF to my package breaks something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I removed the dots in the name of the files.
CCRExif instead of CCR.Exif.

That was a nasty one.

Comment: That feels like a compiler bug to me

Answer (score 1):

What you report doesn't quite add up. The `GIFImg` unit that is part of the Delphi source does not refer to `CCR.Exif.Consts.SOutOfResources`. And none of the units used by `GIFImg` refer to it either.

So the explanations that seem plausible to me are:

1. You are including a unit called `GIFImg` somewhere in your project.
2. You've found a compiler bug.

The error message `F2051` is emitted typically, in my experience, when you attempt to recompile an RTL/VCL unit but fail to set the project options to match that used by the true RTL/VCL. Alternatively it will be emitted when you recompile an RTL/VCL unit that has modifications in its interface section.

Comment: "What you report doesn't quite add up" - I know. This is why I wanted to separate the EXIF unit/package.

Comment: "You are including a unit called GIFImg somewhere in your project" - When I Control-Click the GifImg it takes me to Embarcadero's file. I will search the entire drive for another PAS file called GifImg.pas

Comment: @Marjan - I just did that. All files are original :( Looks like I will have to reinstall Delphi.

Comment: Reinstalling Delphi not likely to be the solution.

Comment: There is any EXIF-like library in Delphi XE?

Comment: No: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Search/?cx=017600442052825486983%3Adkcrzvfszgk&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&lr=lang_en&q=exif&sa=Go&siteurl=docwiki.embarcadero.com%2FRADStudio%2Fen%2FMain_Page